# PlayCanvas - Not able to see orange box on pointing hiro marker

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, playcanvas

I am expecting to see orange box when i point my mobile towards the hiro marker on my laptop screen.
However i dont see it. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Here is the project that i launch
https://playcanvas.com/editor/scene/1816486

I hit this url from mobile after launching the above app
https://launch.playcanvas.com/1816486

I point it my mobile to hiro marker
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hiro_marker_ARjs.png

Why cant i see the orange box displayed when in the script for the marker, i have imported hiro.patt